# "Failed to build native gem extension" when attempting "gem install websocket-driver"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Context:
I ran `gem uninstall --all` in a "scorched-earth" attempt to debug a persistent Capybara error I was experiencing.  My plan was to then run `bundle install` in the folder where my Gemfile is, and re-install the necessary gems with their correct versions.  However, running that command resulted in the following:

```
Could not find addressable-2.3.6 in any of the sources
```

So I attempted to install the `addressable` gem by itself (i.e. `gem install addressable`), and that seemed to work fine.  However when I re-ran `bundle install`, I got the following:

```
Could not find websocket-driver-0.3.4 in any of the sources
```

Attempting the same strategy (`gem install websocket-driver`) resulted in the following:

```
Fetching: websocket-driver-0.3.4.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing websocket-driver:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/richiethomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb

creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling websocket_mask.c
make: *** [websocket_mask.o] Segmentation fault: 11

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/richiethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/websocket-driver-0.3.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/richiethomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/1.9.1/websocket-driver-0.3.4/gem_make.out
```

The contents of the gem_make.out file referenced above are:

```
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling websocket_mask.c
make: *** [websocket_mask.o] Segmentation fault: 11

make failed, exit code 2
```

My best guess is that I was too hasty in uninstalling all the things, and accidentally uninstalled something related to ruby and/or C compilation.  I can't be sure though, because I don't know what a "make" is, or why it failed (according to the .out file).

UPDATE:
I tried running `xcode-select --install` from the command line, hoping this would solve any potential compilation errors, but no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`, and this allowed me to install the version of websocket-driver that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me on Win 7 x64 was

```
gem install --verbose websocket-driver
```

But that not always works for some reason